# HTML - dynamic url a href

Tags: html, url, href

I'm completely new to the world of HTML.

I have an HTML file that contains a link similar to below:

```
<tr><a href=Report_201508_11Aug15.pdf>Report_11Aug15</a></tr>
```

the '201508_11Aug15' represents the date of the report.

Instead of hardcoding the date for each report, I would instead like to use a date function to locate the report and display a link for it.

so it would become 
`<tr><a href=Report_(Today's date in format above).pdf>Report_(Today's date in format above)</a></tr>`

Please advise on how to achieve this? I would then want to go to older dates (e.g. Today's date - 1, -2, - 3 etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide your code you done so far.

Comment: Andreu - what is jinja2?

Comment: Irshad, I have no code so far, what is included up there is what is currently used, and it is updated each day to include the latest report via VBA macro, I would like this to be more dynamic in that when the report arrives tomorrow, the top link on the list is for that report and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your are looking for client side solution you can do this using Javascript.

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var name='Report_';
name+=d.getFullYear();
name+=month.toString().length==1?('0'+month):month;
name+='_';
name+=d.getDate()+1;
name+=monthNames[month];
name+=d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);
name+='.pdf';
```

Fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/51r3z9gt/)

Comment: Thanks or the response and the Demo, this will definitely work, one thing I need to get working is the Month in number format. I understand that in java months are numbered 0-11 rather than 1-12? Making August(08) appearing as 07 in the example, how can I change this to show 08 and what happens when we move into double-digit months (will October be 10 or 010)?

Comment: just add 1 to getMonth() result. `d.getMonth() + 1`

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, just one last question, what do you mean by 'client side solution'? When I export the script out from JSFiddle it doesn't seem to work as it does on JSFiddle.

Comment: Please create a new thread and post your HTML markup with script & explain briefly what doesn't work .